# How I can execute a exe file with parameter in C# with my User ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, process, exe

net application that use the process class for execute a exe with parameter. My Problem is that it works a few day good but now I dont can execute this exe with the parameter -.-

If I try it manuell with a terminal than it works but if I do it with C# Code than I get a message that I dont can create the file.

```
*** ERROR *** Cannot create qrun.inf file
```

Here is my c# code:

```
string cmd = Server.MapPath(@"~/exe/lstc_qrun.exe -s server01 -R");

string output = ExecuteCommand(cmd);

//Output = "*** ERROR *** Cannot create qrun.inf file"
```

here is the ExecuteCommand Method:

```
public static string ExecuteCommand(string command)
        {
            int exitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;

            try
            {
                processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
                processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;


                using (process = Process.Start(processInfo))
                {
                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    exitCode = process.ExitCode;

                    return output;
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return "error: " + ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

What can I do ..I work on my local machine :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ed04yy3t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reference of Process.Start() :

```
public static Process Start(
    string fileName,
    string arguments,
    string userName,
    SecureString password,
    string domain
)
```

or you can just fill the ProcessStartInfo members :

```
processInfo.Username = 'Username' ;
processInfo.Password = 'Password' ;
processInfo.Domain  = 'MyDomain' ;
```